# Using nginx to serve meta tiles

Tags: apache, nginx, openstreetmap, mapnik

Is there an nginx extension that can serve pre-renderd mod_tile metatiles? Alternatively, is there any performance hit from using nginx to serve non-meta map tiles?

Thank you for any help.

Cheers.